# Period of a module vs element

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I believe that my notes are a little off because it seems that in one instance per$(M)$ is a set and in another case it's an element.  Maybe a computation from the notes would help clarify the situation.

For starters, some definitions:
Let $M$ be a module over a pid $D$ and let $x\in M$. Then $\gamma_x : D\to M$ be given by $d\mapsto d.x$. 
Then a generating element of $\ker(\gamma_x)=\{d|d.x=0\}$ is called the period of $x$, denoted per$(x)$.

We define the period of $M$ as per$(M):=\{ d| d.x=0 \text{ for all } x\in M\} $

(is this definition correct?)

Here's an example I'm stuck on, "Now let $M$ be a finitely generated torsion module (i.e. Tor$(M)=M$) over the pid $D$.  If $M=\langle x_1,...,x_n \rangle $then it is an easy exercise to show that per$(M)=lcm (per(x_i))=d\neq 0$.  Then if one has $d=p_1^{\nu_1}\cdots p_n^{\nu_n}$, one has that $$M=M(p_1^{\nu_1})\oplus \cdots \oplus M(p_n^{\nu_n})$$

Where $M(d):=\ker(\gamma_d)$. "

Note: the $=$ to the left of $d$ in $=d\neq 0$ might more appropriately be $=:$ but I'm not sure, $d$ just appeared suddenly from nowhere.

Comment: Yes it's defining $d$ to be the period of $M$. Is that your question?

Comment: No, lol.  I'm not sure if per(M) ={d|d.x=0 for all x in M} is appropriate, because here it's a set and later in the notes (about 10 pages later) it becomes an element (I believe a rational number).  In any case, I think it would help to show the "easy exercise" and the centered equation since I'm confused on the defintion; knowing the definition and seeing a clean proof where it is used will absolutely help (these are quite poorly written notes unfortunately)

Comment: The principal ideal and its principal generator are sometimes interchanged. Is that actually causing you any problems?

Comment: Yes, I guess as long as that's the case that helps a little.  Still not seeing the rest of the question.  I'll work on it for a little and if I get something I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Say $D$ is a PID and $M$ is a $D$-module. Suppose further that $dM=0$ for $d\in D$, and that we have a factorization $d=\ell_1\ell_2\cdots\ell_n$ where the $\ell_i$s are pairwise coprime (i.e. $(\ell_i,\ell_j)=D$). Then

$$M=M(\ell_1)\oplus M(\ell_2)\oplus\cdots\oplus M(\ell_n)$$

where we define $M(\ell)=\{m\in M:\ell m=0\}$.

There is an inclusion in one direction. (Try to prove that no nonzero element of $M$ can be in $M(\ell_i)$ for two distinct $i$.) For the other direction, we need to construct a map $M\to\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M(\ell_i)$ out of maps $M\to M(\ell_i)$. The maps $M\to M(\ell_i)$ need to be the identity on the submodule $M(\ell_i)$ within $M$ but in a sense annihilate "everything else." Thus, make them out to be the multiplication maps $m\mapsto t_i m$ where $t_i$ is $1$ mod $\ell_i$ and $0$ mod $\ell_j$ for $j\ne i$. I leave it to you to prove that this works out.

Comment: I'm a bit lost lost why coprime implies $(l_i,l_j)=D$, in fact I'm not sure I understand what $(l_i,l_j)$ means.  Is this the same as $\langle l_i,l_j \rangle$?  In any case, what do you mean by your notation?

Comment: I'm also not sure the map $m\mapsto t_im$ makes sense?  I don't understand if $m$ goes to $t_i m  $ then when would the case $j\neq i$ occur?  I'm just lost in notation.

Comment: $(l_i,l_j)$ denotes the ideal generated by $l_i$  and $l_j$. In a PID, a generator of this ideal is called a $\gcd$ of $l_i$  and $l_j$. That's why coprime translates into $(l_i,l_j)=(1)=D$.

Comment: Two ideals $I$ and $J$ of a ring $R$ are called coprime if $1\in I+J$ (usually stated as $R=I+J$). In the case of $I$ and $J$ being principal ideals in $\Bbb Z$, this is basically a statement of Bezout's identity. Note that the familiar definition of coprimality "share no common factor" is not as useful in a general domain, since that property can't be leveraged for this kind of Chinese Remainder Theorem argument. Heck, you can't even factor an arbitrary $d$ into a product of primes in an arbitrary domain!

Comment: The map $M\to M(\ell_1)$ is $m\mapsto t_1m$. The map $M\to M(\ell_2)$ is $m\mapsto t_2m$. And so on. There are $n$ different maps. The idea is that multiplication-by-a-scalar-in-$D$ is a type of module homomorphism we know how to construct, and on the assumption that $M=\bigoplus M(\ell_i)$, if the projection $M\to M(\ell_i)$ is going to wind up being multiplication by a scalar $t_i$ we can rig it to work out by making $t_i$ act as $1$ mod $\ell_i$ and act as $0$ mod other $\ell_j$s. It might be helpful to think about $D=\Bbb Z$ and $M$ being a finite abelian group - we get the primary decomp.